¿Por qué existen dos operadores de igualdad en Javascript "==" y "===" si hacen lo mismo?
Estoy siguiendo un tutorial donde todas las comparaciones están hechas con === (3 =) en vez de == (2 =). Al reemplazar === por == el código sigue funcionando como lo esperado, por ejemplo:
let variable1 = "a";
let variable2 = "a";

if (variable1 === variable2) {
    console.log("son iguales")
}

if (variable1 == variable2) {
    console.log("son iguales")
}

¿Por qué existen estas 2 formas de comparar si hacen lo mismo?

El título de tu pregunta sugiere que la misma está basada en opiniones, sin embargo, el contenido sugiere una pregunta cuya respuesta es más objetiva. Debido a que las preguntas basadas en opiniones van en contra de los lineamientos de la comunidad, es mejor que cambies el título de tu pregunta a algo más objetivo.

Muchas gracias @Rodrigo modificaré la pregunta para hacerla más objetiva

Por qué no lo sé. Habría que preguntarle a los creadores del lenguaje. Semánticamente === significa igual así que ambos operandos deben ser del mismo tipo. == es más laxo y significa parecido.

¿La razón? Javascript es un lenguaje mal diseñado, donde los problemas abundan.

La diferencia es que == compara solo el valor,
y === compara el valor y el tipo del valor, ya sea una cadena o número.


const num = "1"
const string = "a"


console.log(1 == num)
console.log(1 === num)

console.log("a" == string)
console.log("a" === string)



Al usar  == se compara el valor; si un número está declarado como "1", será true. Pero al usar === se compara el tipo de la variable y el valor.
Usar en una string que contiene un carácter alfabético verificará tanto el valor como el tipo.
Por lo tanto, se usa más === que compara el tipo y el valor que == que solo compara el valor.


Por qué existen estas 2 formas de comparar si hacen lo mismo?

No hacen lo mismo.
En el primer caso, ==, se comparan únicamente los valores


console.log(0 == false) // true
console.log(1 == "1") // true



Esto da true debido a que 0 es igual a false en JavaScript, y en muchos otros lenguajes, de este modo, estás comparando que los dos lados representen el mismo valor, independientemente de su tipo de dato; es decir que mientras ambos lados de la igualdad presenten el mismo valor (sin tomar en cuenta el tipo de dato, como "1" y 1), el resultado será true
Pero si usas === la situación cambia. En este caso, estás comparando el valor de una manera más estricta, pues ambos lados deben ser exactamente iguales, lo cual significa que incluso los tipo de dato deben ser iguales.


console.log(0 === false) // false - 0 y false no tienen el mismo tipo de dato
console.log("1" === 1) // false



Para más información, puedes leer: Comparadores de igualdad e identidad.
